# Should I implement this as a Sink or an OutputFilter with boost::iostreams?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams

I use a `boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream` to write debug logs for my application. I want to improve my debug logging by keeping the last 100 or so entries and saving them to a file in the event of a crash.

I imagine I can do this in two ways:

1. I can implement an OutputFilter that is a "no-op" on the stream data but keeps a limited list of the entries in some member variable.
2. I can implement a Sink that does something similar.

I see two advantages to option 1: I do not need to "tee" the stream to two destinations and there is a convenient `basic_line_filter` base-class that makes its implementation quite easy. But conceptually option 2 seems more correct. What other wisdom am I missing? What do you recommend? Is there a third/fourth way?

Comment: The forty-second way is to ... us a logging API. Instead of "magically" intercepting log output. Because that's a leaky abstraction and, as you found out, not amenable to refactoring.

Comment: @sehe, I don't understand. :( What logging API are you referring to?

Comment: Using `boost::iostreams::tee_filter` allows you to convert any sink into a filter (which both writes to the sink and sends data down the pipeline unmodified).

Comment: Boost.Log looks very promising.